# Shortcode in a $output statement

Tags: php, shortcode

I have a function that outputs HTML and in that list of $output statements I need to output the code which already resides in a shortcode for use elsewhere.

```
$output = 'shortcode here';
```

I attempted the `do_shortcode()` avenue only to get the WSOD :)

What would be the proper way to declare the shortcode in such a statement?

Comment: You've tried `do_shortcode( '[shortcode_here]' );` and it fails? Does the shortcode work properly when added to the content as normal?

Comment: I think the single quotes around the shortcode may be where I failed. I will retry. Thanks!

Comment: That should be $output .= do_shortcode ('[shortcode here]');   Correct?